# How to perform a segue if child does not exist in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to check if a user has been banned from a group before to let him have access to the group chat and then perform a segue toward the next view controller.

For that I use exist(). When the child exists, the code works perfectly but when the child does not exist, nothing happens.

I tried to change   `blockedUserDB.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in` for  `blockedUserDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value` without success. I also tried to perform the segue in putting `performSegue(withIdentifier: "toConversationControler", sender: Any?.self)` in another function triggered when the node does not exist ...

Here is my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.selectedGroupID = "\(groupArray[indexPath.row].documentID)"

    // Check if user blocked
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid as String

    // 1 - set breakpoint here
    let blockedUserDB = self.ref2.child("blocked").child(self.selectedGroupID).child(uid)

    blockedUserDB.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        // 2 - does this print?
        print("snapshot.exists() ==", snapshot.exists())

        if snapshot.exists(){

            // 3 - does this print?
            print("true rooms exist")

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! String

            print("\(snapshotValue) the value")

            self.blockUserCheck = snapshotValue

            print(self.blockUserCheck)

            if self.blockUserCheck == "true" {
                SPAlert.present(message: "You have been banned from this group")
            }
            else
            {
                print("performSegue!")

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toConversationControler", sender: Any?.self)

                print("selected group \(self.selectedGroupID)")

            }

        }
        else
        {
            // 4 - does this print?
            print("snapshot.exists() was false!")

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toConversationControler", sender: Any?.self)

        }

    })

}
```

And here is how I prepared for segue:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        guard let identifier = segue.identifier else {
            assertionFailure("Segue had no idientifier")
            return
        }

        if identifier == "toConversationControler" {

            let vc = segue.destination as! ConversationViewController
            vc.finalGroup = self.selectedGroupID
            vc.groupName = self.selectedGroupName
            vc.city = self.finalCity
            vc.language = self.selectedLanguage
            vc.info = self.selectedInfo
        }

        else if identifier == "toNewConvVC" {

            let newConvVC = segue.destination as! NewGroupViewController
            newConvVC.city = self.finalCity

        }

        else {

             assertionFailure("Did not recognize storyboard identifier")
        }

    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"nothing happens"* -- is nothing happening when you call `self.performSegue(...)`? Or is that line never being reached? Set a breakpoint on your `self.selectedGroupID = ...` line and step through in debug so you can see where your code is going.

Comment: I set the breakpoint as you advise me and I confirm the line is never reached.

Comment: OK - you said *"When the child exists, the code works perfectly..."* -- now you stepped through in debug and *"confirm the line is never reached"* then you should have seen ***why*** it was never reached. So, where is your logic faulty? What part of your code did you expect to lead to that line but doesn't?

Comment: Sorry I have misread your last comment. This time, I set the breakpoint on `self.selectedGroupID = ...` as requested. And the line is reached without problem. The only line which is not reached is `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toConversationControler", sender: Any?.self)` when the child does not exist

Comment: If  `if snapshot.exists()` is false, your code should fall through to the `else` and perform the segue. So when you're stepping through in debug, what happens that you don't get to the `else` part?

Comment: That de point, in the debug, nothing is written, it's like the `else` is not taking in account. I tried to erase the line `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toConversationControler", sender: Any?.self)` and  pint `print("does not exist")` . But nothing is printed in the debug like if I did not press the cell or like the `else` is not taking in account

Comment: I edited your question... reformatted your code... added a couple `print()` statements... added `// 1 -`, `// 2 -`, `// 3 -`, `// 4 -` comments. I didn't change any executable lines. Run that code, follow the comments, and let's see what happens.

Comment: I executed the code that you have reformatted : - when the child exist `//1`,`//2`,`//3` are printed . When the child does not exist nothing is printed

Comment: OK - that means your code never gets into the `blockedUserDB.observe(...) {` code block. I don't use Firebase, but it appears you are creating an **observer** to run when a child is added to the database. It doesn't seem to make any sense to add an observer every time you select a row from a table.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have fixed the issue

Comment: Here is the fixed code:  `blockedUserDB.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in ...` replaced by   `blockedUserDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in ...
`